# Goodman furnace only lighting for about 60 seconds then flame goes out and get error code 4

Tags: heating

after about 30 seconds furnace lights up again then goes out again after about 60 seconds. filter is clean, air fan is blowing cool air cleaned flame sensor, pressure switch is not blocked but i dont hear a clicking(maybe thats cus i`m deaf lol) Enducer was replaced 2yrs ago.

Comment: it will try 4 times to ignite

Comment: Flame sensor has to deliver >700 mV to the circuit

Comment: it ignites every time but flame goes out about every 60 seconds then fires up again after about a minute.

Comment: [Goodman error codes with troubleshooting steps](https://www.google.com/search?q=goodman+furnace+error+codes)

Comment: i had a repair guy come out to give a quote think he was an idiot, didnt do much at all. Said it was the fan board which i replaced lol.

Comment: It could be your gas supply

Comment: thanks everyone for the input. Just have get a different repair to come out.

Comment: There is noting better then eyes on hands on

Comment: Test your pressure switch, high limit is a common error with a bad pressure switch. Otherwise agreed, get a different repair person in.

Comment: Sounds like it might be a thermocouple not be sensing that the flame is burning so the furnace cuts off the supply to avoid filling the room with unignited gas. Could also be a problem with the supply pressure.

Comment: Update new repair guy came out, it turned out to be a bad capicitor on the fan blower. Then fan was turning too slow.